# Read data from excel file using the .Net ExcelReaderFactory library in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

How can I read data from an excel file that is submitted through an HTML form using the ExcelReaderFactory C# library in .Net?
Specifically, how do I read data from a specific sheet (i.e the second sheet) in the excel file?

I already have an HTML form with an input type [file] and a controller that is receiving the submitted excel file, see below;

> HTML Form

```
<form method="POST" asp-action="DataMigration" asp-controller="DataMigration" 
  enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="data" accept=".xlsx, .xls, .csv" required>
  <input type="submit" value="Upload Data" />
</form>
```

> POST Controller

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult DataMigration(IFormFile data)
{
    try
    {
        //validate uploaded file
        if (data == null || data.Length <= 0)
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }

        //create destination dir to save uploaded excel file
        var path = Path.Combine(_environment.WebRootPath, "MyDestinationDirName");
        if (!Directory.Exists(path))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
        }

        //get complete file path [destinationPath/fileName]
        string filePath;
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(data.FileName);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
        {
            filePath = Path.Combine(path, fileName);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }

        //move file to destination dir
        using var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);
        data.CopyTo(fileStream);

        //Now how do I read this excel file???
        //...
        //...
        //...
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.writeLine(e);
    }

    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Excel file

[image]

> HTML form that submits excel file via POST method

```
<form method="POST" asp-action="DataMigration" asp-controller="DataMigration" 
  enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="data" accept=".xlsx, .xls, .csv" required>
  <input type="submit" value="Upload Data" />
</form>
```

> POST controller that receives submitted excel file and reads the second sheet (cell by cell) using the ExcelReaderFactory library.

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult DataMigration(IFormFile data)
{
    try
    {
        //validate uploaded file
        if (data == null || data.Length <= 0)
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }

        //create destination dir to save uploaded excel file
        var path = Path.Combine(_environment.WebRootPath, "YouDestinationDirName");
        if (!Directory.Exists(path))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
        }

        //get complete file path [destinationPath/fileName]
        string filePath;
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(data.FileName);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
        {
            filePath = Path.Combine(path, fileName);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }

        //move file to destination dir
        using var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);
        data.CopyTo(fileStream);


        //get & read uploaded excel file using the ExcelReaderFactory library
        Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
        using var stream = System.IO.File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        using var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream);

        //loop through each excel sheet
        int sheetCount = 1;
        do
        {
           
            if(sheetCount != 2) continue; //only read data from the second sheet in excel file

            while (reader.Read()) // loop through each row  
            {
                //Read each cell values in current row
                var firstName = reader.GetValue(0).ToString(); //JOHN
                var lastName = reader.GetValue(1).ToString(); //DOE
                var age = reader.GetValue(2).ToString();     //28
                //etc...

                //then save these cell values to db or something...
            }

            //break; //add break if you only want to read the first excel sheet
          
            sheetCount++;
            
        } while (reader.NextResult()); //Move to next sheet
        
        Console.writeLine("success");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.writeLine(e);
    }

    return View();
}
```

Comment: This is very inefficient.  Why are you saving to disk?  Why do you not simply use a MemoryStream?

Comment: Wise. I kinda thought so too. Let me revise my answer.

Comment: Please specify where you got the '_environment' variable. I understand why it's there, I just need the declaration.

Comment: @VillageSavers If you don't save to disk first, there is no need for it